# Entityframework Join using join method and lambdas

Tags: entity-framework, join, lambda

It seems there are different ways to do joins using linq. One is more straightforward and involves just joining tables like this:

```
var found = from c in s.categories
            join cm in s.categorymaps on c.CategoryId equals cm.ChildCategoryId
            select c;
```

There is another way using lambdas and I'm having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to join using this syntax. Can anyone provide links to detailed explanations and lots of examples? Or just simply demonstrate using examples how to use this rather confusing syntax?

```
var x = _session.All<category>().Join<categorymap,category, ....
```

Answer (score 148):

Generally i prefer the lambda syntax with LINQ, but `Join` is one example where i prefer the query syntax - purely for readability.

Nonetheless, here is the equivalent of your above query (i think, untested):

```
var query = db.Categories         // source
   .Join(db.CategoryMaps,         // target
      c => c.CategoryId,          // FK
      cm => cm.ChildCategoryId,   // PK
      (c, cm) => new { Category = c, CategoryMaps = cm }) // project result
   .Select(x => x.Category);  // select result
```

You might have to fiddle with the projection depending on what you want to return, but that's the jist of it.

Comment: Best explantion that I found so far, I was able to resolve my join issues, thank you

Comment: Who in MS sat there and decided this syntax is sane? I wanna meet him and axe him a question or two

Comment: One of the downsides of code like this is the Anonymous Class you get from Join, which then makes the results hard to pass around, for example to a View, Controller, or event framework. I like to write explicit Intermediary classes, with exactly the mix of properties I care about in the Join. The result is I get strong typing, and better SQL performance because the list of columns returned is more constrained than full rows.

Answer (score 13):

You can find a few examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669071.aspx):

> ```
> // Fill the DataSet.
> DataSet ds = new DataSet();
> ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
> FillDataSet(ds);
>
> DataTable contacts = ds.Tables["Contact"];
> DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];
>
> var query =
>     contacts.AsEnumerable().Join(orders.AsEnumerable(),
>     order => order.Field<Int32>("ContactID"),
>     contact => contact.Field<Int32>("ContactID"),
>     (contact, order) => new
>     {
>         ContactID = contact.Field<Int32>("ContactID"),
>         SalesOrderID = order.Field<Int32>("SalesOrderID"),
>         FirstName = contact.Field<string>("FirstName"),
>         Lastname = contact.Field<string>("Lastname"),
>         TotalDue = order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue")
>     });
>
>
> foreach (var contact_order in query)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("ContactID: {0} "
>                     + "SalesOrderID: {1} "
>                     + "FirstName: {2} "
>                     + "Lastname: {3} "
>                     + "TotalDue: {4}",
>         contact_order.ContactID,
>         contact_order.SalesOrderID,
>         contact_order.FirstName,
>         contact_order.Lastname,
>         contact_order.TotalDue);
> }
> ```

Or just google for 'linq join method syntax'.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I found this very useful link which really explains the rather complex join() method so thought I would share it for others to learn

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured navigation property 1-n I would recommend you to use:

```
var query = db.Categories                                  // source
   .SelectMany(c=>c.CategoryMaps,                          // join
      (c, cm) => new { Category = c, CategoryMaps = cm })  // project result
   .Select(x => x.Category);                               // select result
```

Much more clearer to me and looks better with multiple nested joins.