# SQL to Entities syntax for INNER JOIN and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, frameworks, entity

I'm a bit fresh to Entity Framework, and need some advice on the syntax. My goal is to retrieve a distinct list of filtered equipment from one table and match them to ID's in another table.

Here is the RAW SQL that accomplishes the JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DowntimeReasons.Equipment, Equipment.ID 
FROM DowntimeReasons INNER JOIN Equipment 
ON DowntimeReasons.Equipment = Equipment.Equipment 
WHERE DowntimeReasons.Emergency = 1
```

I've been able to recreate the distinct list of equipment in SQL to Entities with the following code.

```
            var distinctEquipmentList = db.DowntimeReasons
                .Where(x => x.Emergency == true)
                .Distinct()
                .Select(x => x.Equipment)
                .ToList();
```

But how do I join this list to the IDs I need from the other table?  I'm open to query syntax or method syntax.  Heck, as I'm learning solo, I'm open to any help! Thank you!

Comment: I think the following will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010110/entityframework-join-using-join-method-and-lambadas

Comment: @Andy Nichols The link you provided discusses how to execute a JOIN.  I need help performing an INNER JOIN with DISTINCT.

Comment: Are the relationships one-to-many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at what your entities look like, here's a shot a it.

You can try something like this:

```
var query = (from dr in db.DowntimeReasons
            join e in db.Equipments on dr.Equipment equals e.Equipment
            where e.Emergency
            select e.Equipment).Distinct().ToList();
```

If this doesn't work, then please post your entities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I'll give this a shot later on today!  I'll update the comment with results.

Comment: The above example helped, but I ended up going a different route.