# generic repository pattern with joins

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have begun exploring the repository pattern with entity framework (6.x) by reading what I consider the best basic treatment of the subject in this article: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm

unfortunately it does not address joins. Using a generic repository, how does one join to an arbitrary number of other entities/repositories?

as of now I have this the generic interface:

```
    interface IGenericRepository<T> where T: class
{
    IEnumerable<T> SelectAll();
    T SelectByID(object id);
    void Insert(T obj);
    void Update(T obj);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Save();

}

    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private SocialMediaEntities db = null;
    private DbSet<T> table = null;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        this.db = new SocialMediaEntities();
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public GenericRepository(SocialMediaEntities db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return table.ToList();
    }

    public T SelectByID(object id)
    {
        return table.Find(id);
    }

    public void Insert(T obj)
    {
        table.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        table.Attach(obj);
        db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        T existing = table.Find(id);
        table.Remove(existing);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

}

perhaps the customer, customer order example is a good choice to illustrate. thanks.

---

After asking my question I found another SO question whose answer led to the 
following solution for me which works. Question is have I mixed idioms? Is this
approach keeping within the generic repository pattern?

(question was [Entityframework Join using join method and lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010110/entityframework-join-using-join-method-and-lambdas))

```
using (CommerceEntities ce = new CommerceEntities())
{
     // the repository is Company
     var results = repository.SelectAll()
    .Join(ce.Orders,                          // target
    p => p.OrderID,                           // FK
    s => s.ID,                                // PK
    (p, s) => new { Order = s, Company = p }) // project result
    .Select(x => x.Company).ToList();         // select result
}
```

after studying the first answer given, it seems much more in the spirit of generic repository pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create several overloads for the GetAll method. Like this:

```
//get all, including orderby clause, and includes
//usage: var s = repository.GetAll(i => i.Name, false, i => i.NavigationProperty);
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<TOrderKey>(Expression<Func<T, TOrderKey>> orderbyExp, 
                                        Boolean descending, 
                                        params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] includeExps)
{
    var query = table.AsQueryable();
    query = !descending ? query.OrderBy(orderByExp) : query.OrderByDescending(orderByExp);
    if (includeExps != null)
       query = includeExps.Aggregate(query, (current, exp) => current.Include(exp));        

   return query.ToList();
}


//get all, including select clause, orderby clause, and includes
//usage: var s = repository.GetAll(i => new { Name = i.Name }, i => i.Name, false, i => i.NavigationProperty
public IEnumerable<TReturn> GetAll<TReturn, TOrderKey>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> selectExp,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, TOrderKey>> orderExp, 
                                                       Boolean descending, 
                                                       params Expression<Func<T, Object>>[] includeExps)
{
     var query = table.AsQueryable();
     query = !descending ? query.OrderBy(orderByExp) : query.OrderByDescending(orderByExp);
     if (includeExps != null)
       query = includeExps.Aggregate(query, (current, exp) => current.Include(exp));  

      return query.Select(selectExp).ToList();
}


//get all, including select clause, where clause, order by clause, and includes
//usage: var s = repository.GetAll(i => new { i.Name }, i => i.Name.Contains('John'), i => i.Name, false, i => i.NavigationProperty
public IEnumerable<TReturn> GetAll<TReturn, TOrderKey>(Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> selectExp,
                                                       Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> whereExp, 
                                                       Expression<Func<T, TOrderKey>> orderbyExp,
                                                       Boolean descending,
                                                       params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeExps)
{
    var query = table.Where(whereExp);
    query = !descending ? query.OrderBy(orderbyExp) : query.OrderByDescending(orderbyExp);
    if (includeExps != null)
      query = includeExps.Aggregate(query, (current, exp) => current.Include(exp));

    return query.Select(selectExp).ToList();
}
```

The above methods is just an example. You should recreate them as you need.