# c# linq How can I perform this join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having trouble joining these two tables.

I have these 2 tables

```
SurveySectionTable
-SurveySectionId-(pk)
-surveyId
-SurveySectionName
-comments
-score
...

SurveySectionLoalocazationTable
-SurveySectionLocalizationId-(pk)
-SurveySectionId-(fk)
-SurveySectionName
-comments
...
```

Using Linq extension methods I want join the two tables based on the SurveySectionId and get a result like this

```
NewResult
-SurveySectionId
-surveyId(from SurveySectionTable)
-SurveySectionName (from SurveySectionLocalizationTable)
-comments(from SurveySectionLocalizationTable)
-score (from SurveySectionTable)
    ...
```

The logic I have looks like this, is there a better way of doing this?

```
    public async Task<SurveySectionEditViewModel> GetSurveySectionEditLocalizationVm(Guid surveySectionId, Guid localizationId)
    {   
       var defaultTable = await UOF.SurveySectionService.GetById(surveySectionId);

       var localizationTable = //get by both parameters;

       var result = new SurveySectionEditViewModel
        {
           SurveySectionId = surveySectionId,
           SurveyId = defaultTable.SurveyId,
           SurveySectionName = localizationTable.SurveySectionName,
           Comments = localizatoinTable.Comments,
           Score = defaultTable.Score
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? How does your entity classes look like? Did you model the relationships between tables as navigation properties in the entity classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL to create a view. Then query the view using EF.

Whenever you get stuck with EF, the right answer is almost always "create a view".

Comment: That is not an option, I am not allowed to create them.

Comment: Well I can offer you a link for doing it entirely in EF. But really, it is a clumsy and error prone method that I strongly discourage unless you are querying a database owned by a 3rd party vendor for which literally no changes are allowed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010110/entityframework-join-using-join-method-and-lambdas

Comment: Thanks for that. I did the exact same thing in my first attempt. It looked so bad as an extension method I thought I was doing it wrong.

Comment: Yea, that's the downside of EF. You can do just about anything with it, but most of it feels like a weird hack.